# Question about sylow p-subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question: Find the number of sylow 5-subgroup of group of order 60
My attempt: 
  O(G)=60=2^2•3•5

As,5|60 and 5^2 does not divide 60 so, by sylow first theorem G must have at least one sylow 5-subgroup of order 5.
Now by sylow 3rd theorem number of sylow 5-subgroup say n_5 satisfies,
n_5 = 1+5k and n_5 | 60
Both of above holds for k=0,1.
But in text book they take k= 1 and so n_5 = 6.
Why they take k=1? and not take k=0?

Comment: There must be some information missing, there are groups of order 60 where $n_5=1$ and others where $n_5=6$

Comment: Could it be that book (which one, by the way?) mentions "a **simple** group of order $\;60\;$ ? Or perhaps it is working with $\;A_5\;$ directly? Otherwise, as Merlin comments above, the claim is false.

Answer (score -1):

$n_5$ satisfies two conditions:

1) $n_5\mid |G|/5=12$ which implies $n_5\in \{1,2,3,4,6, 12\}$

2) $n_5\equiv 1 {\pmod 5}$

The two conditions are satisfied only if $n_5=6$.

Comment: Isn't this also true for $n_5=1$?

Comment: This answer seems to miss the obvious $\;n_5=1\;$ ...

Comment: n_5 ≡ 1 mod 5  and  n_5 | 12 so 



→ 5 | n_5  - 1

→ n_5 = 1 + 5k. and n_5  | 12 
 
these two condition satisfied for k = 0 and k = 1

why they choose k= 1 ? (so that they get n_5 = 6)

why they didn't choose k =0?

Comment: Yes the group in question is A5.